# Replicate node_modules folder on a certain date from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package.json and package-lock.json for an typescript Angular/firebase project. When pushing the same version that's in the cloud, the OAuth2 breaks. I believe this is due to new package version.

I want to restore my node_modules folder to the state it had 16th of March when we uploaded the last working version.

Comment: if you have the `package-lock.json` file from that date, you need to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. It will use the `package-lock.json` file to look up the transitive dependencies.

Comment: @Seblor Alright, this sounds like it might be the answer I am looking for. Does `npm ci` yield deterministic results regardless of new minor updates? I recall from looking at my `package-lock.json` the semver had some carets and tildes...

Comment: Yes, `npm ci` will install all dependencies and their dependencies (recursively) exactly as their version are set in the `package-lock.json` file. And since NPM doesn't allow anyone from removing any version oftheir module, unless NPM itself as an issue, you are guaranteed to have the exact same setup. The semver notation you see is just replication in the dependencies in the `package.json` contained in each module, but the versions that will be installed are the one of the actual dependencies.

Comment: I've tried cloning the repo from scratch, `npm cache clear --force`, checking out various versions and still can't get it to work. Thanks for the help anyways @Seblor